# Custom redirect specific page after edit

Tags: redirection

With my Drupal website ( which is much more custom than drupal ) I've got node referenced in another ( ex. an article in a custom page ).

I want the ability to easily edit the referenced content. To do that I've put a button with the link:

```
<?php print $base_url; ?>/node/<?php print $article->nid; ?>/edit?destination=<?php print urlencode('node/'.$node->nid); ?>
```

Sadly Drupal doesn't care about the destination and redirects me to the article node and not the current node it was into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is always a good habit to use **l()** to create links in Drupal. In your case, you can use the below code to create link.

```
l(t('Title'), 'node/' . $article->nid . '/edit', array('query' => array('destination' => 'node/' . $node->nid)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Destination should work. If it doesn't then you could try this way using `hook_form_alter` to make it work.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
        if($form_id == 'your_form_id') {
                $destination = $_GET['destination']; 
                $form_state['redirect'] = $destination;
        }
}
```